# jquery sequential animation

Tags: jquery, animation, sequential

i'm trying to replicate this animation

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedContentMenu/

i'm not able to animate the menu items, than sliding up sequentially

```
    $('#bar').animate(
    {width: '100%'},
    {duration: 500,
    specialEasing: {width: 'linear'},
    complete: function() {
        $('li').each( function() {
                $(this).animate(
                    {top:'0px'},
                    {queue: true, duration: 200, specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutBack'},
                }); 
        });
    }
});
```

In this way the menu items are animated simultaneously.....what's wrong?

Comment: thanks Nick, your fist solution work fine!! the second one would be better, but don't work for me.... However I am satisfied with the first solution. thanks again.

Comment: I was looking to do a very similar thing as this question, so I created a small Jquery plugin (https://github.com/fillswitch/Jquery-Sequential-Animations). Hope it helps some others out!

Answer (score 10):

Since the queue is *per element*, nothing is actually queueing here, that's why they're all animating at once.  There are a few ways to do this though.  One simple way to do this with a small number of items is with [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), like this:

```
$('#bar').animate(
    {width: '100%'},
    {duration: 500,
    specialEasing: {width: 'linear'},
    complete: function() {
        $('li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay(i*200).animate(
                {top:'0px'},
                {queue: true, duration: 200, specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutBack'},
            }); 
        });
    }
});
```

[You can test a demo out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dU2cf/).

What this does is delay the animation 200ms * the index of the element in the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iteration, so the first animations is instant, the second 200ms later, the next 200ms after that, etc.  The reason I recommend this is you don't *have* to use 200ms for the delay, you can use a smaller number and have the animations overlap a bit, which seems to be the effect you're after.

Another way to do this (more verbose, sequential only, and allows no overlap) is to use [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to build your own, for example:

```
$('#bar').animate(
    {width: '100%'},
    {duration: 500,
    specialEasing: {width: 'linear'},
    complete: function() {
        $('li').each(function() {
            $(document).queue(function(n) {
              $(this).animate(
                {top:'0px'},
                {queue: true, duration: 200, specialEasing: {top: 'easeOutBack'},
                complete: n //call the next item in the queue             
              }); 
            });
        });
    }
});
```

[You can test that version out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/sU98J/).

Answer (score 0):

Queue is unique for each element which means each element has its own independent queue.
Use a callback after the animation has finished for each item.
Example: If you have five li tags, use a particular class for first four of them and add a callback to that class's animation to execute the animation of the next element.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for sequential animation:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#bullet-' + i).delay(i * 1000 - 1000).fadeIn('fast', function () {
        var id = this
        setTimeout (function () {$(id).css('color', 'lightgray');}, 1500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Array to contain the elements:

```
var Menus = ['menu_1', 'menu_2', 'menu_3', 'menu _4', 'menu _5'];
```

Then you define a for loop for the elements, increasing the value (250ms) each loop round:

```
function myFn(time){
    for(var i = 0; i < Menus.length; i++){
      $('#' + Menus[i]).animate({'opacity' : 1}, time, 'easeInOutQuad');
      time = ++time + 250;
    };
  };
```

and call the function defining the starting value in ms:

```
myFn(500);
```