# Make an array of elements by class name, and show those elements sequentially on document ready

Tags: jquery

As part of an introductory animation on my site, I am attempting to have my navigation buttons show sequentially.

As the animation should go as follows:

1. The main image `#lines_home` fades in
2. The header `#header` fades in
3. The navigation buttons `.nav_button` show fast one by one sequentially. There are 4 elements with the `.nav_button` class.

All elements are initially hidden, and the `.nav_sub` divs are show when a `.nav_button` is clicked.

The DOM (nav section only):

```
<div id="nav">
   <div id="create" class="nav_button">
      <span class="nav_text">CREATE</span>
   </div>
   <div id="create_sub" class="nav_sub">
      <ul class="nav_sub_text">
         <li id="architecture">Architectural Design</li>
         <li id="web">Web Development</li>
         <li id="lighter">Lighter Underground</li>
         <li id="digital_art">Digital Art</li>
         <li id="guitar">Guitar</li>
         <li id="sculpture">Sculpture</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="capture" class="nav_button">
      <span class="nav_text">CAPTURE</span>
   </div>
   <div id="capture_sub" class="nav_sub">
      <ul class="nav_sub_text">
         <li id="seattle">Seattle 2012</li>
         <li id="burningman">Burning Man 2011</li>
         <li id="sanfrancisco">San Francisco 2011</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="blog" class="nav_button">
      <span class="nav_text">BLOG</span>
   </div>
   <div id="blog_sub" class="nav_sub" >
      <ul class="nav_sub_text">
         <li>SL8</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="about" class="nav_button">
      <span class="nav_text">ABOUT</span>
   </div>
   <div id="about_sub" class="nav_sub" >
      <ul class="nav_sub_text">
         <li id="bio">Biography</li>
         <li id="resume">Resum&eacute;</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

The scripting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = document.getElementsByClass('.nav_button');
    var buttonArr = jQuery.makeArray(button);
    $('#lines_home').fadeIn(500, function(){
    $('#header').delay(100).fadeIn(500, function(){
        $(buttonArr[0]).show('fast', function () {
            $(buttonArr[1]).show('fast', function () {
                $(buttonArr[2]).show('fast', function () {
                    $(buttonArr[3]).show('fast');
                });
            });
        });
    });
    });
});
```

However, this does not appear to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why make an array just to convert each element back into jQuery individually? Instead, work with the original `button` object all through.

Comment: Why not use jQuery selector if you have jquery?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6562525/145346

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I'm not sure what you mean, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @fudgey Thank you! the solution on the page you linked to worked for me with some tweaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with recursive function calls to handle any (small) number of buttons:

```
$(function() {
    var $buttons = $('.nav_button');
    function fadeInButton(n) {
        if (n < $buttons.length) {
            $buttons.eq(n).delay(250).show('fast', function() {
                fadeInButton(n + 1);
            });
        }
    }
    $('#lines_home').fadeIn(500, function(){
        $('#header').delay(100).fadeIn(500, function(){
            fadeInButton(0);
        });
    });
}
```

This is essentially your original code but differently proceduralised, and is, IMHO, a better approach than predicting the start points for each fadein and setting multiple timeouts.

The delay can be adjusted down to zero or increased as desired.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjctu/)

Comment: Thank you! this works great. I found a slightly more streamlined method based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of to do this. I am torn as to which one is cleaner.

1) With delays

```
$(function() {
  var $home = $('#lines_home'),
      $header = $('#header'),
      $buttons = $('.nav_button');

  $home.fadeIn(500);
  $header.delay(600).fadeIn(500);
  $buttons.each(function(index) {
    var waitFor = (index * 500) + 1100;
    $(this).delay(waitFor).show();
  });
});
```

2) With callbacks

```
$(function() {
  var enterButtons = function() {
    $('.nav_button').each(function(index) {
      var waitFor = index * 500;
      $(this).delay(waitFor).show();
    });
  };

  var enterHeader = function() {
    $('#header').delay(100).fadeIn(500, enterButtons);
  };

  $('#lines_home').fadeIn(500, enterHeader);
});
```

Neither are tested.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

I tried both of these processes, but with no success. I need to do some research on the API about each, to make sure that I am using it correctly.